# Recyclerview truncated text after scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I get the data from a database, save it in a List and pass the list to a custom recyclerView adapter

The problem is that after scrolling, some words get truncated: why? How can i 
solve that?

check charmander and charmeleon in the second picture, if you need the code just ask what you need

[image: before scrolling]

[image: after scrolling: see charmander and cahrmeleon]

EDIT: 
the adapter:

```
public class PokedexAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PokedexAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<PokemonBase> mData;
private Context context;
private MainActivity mNavigationDrawerCallbacks;
private View mSelectedView;
private int mSelectedPosition;

public PokedexAdapter(List<PokemonBase> data, Context xontext) {
    mData = data;
    context = xontext;
}



public void setFumettiCallbacks(MainActivity navigationDrawerCallbacks) {
    mNavigationDrawerCallbacks = navigationDrawerCallbacks;
}

@Override
public PokedexAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.element, viewGroup, false);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    viewHolder.itemView.setClickable(true);
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, PokemonActivity.class);


            intent.putExtra("poke", mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).numero);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {



            Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create( (View)viewHolder.img, "profile");


            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation((MainActivity)context,(View)viewHolder.img, "profile");


            context.startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());}
            else
                context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });



    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PokedexAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) { //here i set the data

    viewHolder.nome.setText(getStringIdentifier(context, mData.get(i).nome));
    viewHolder.tipouno.setText(getStringIdentifier(context, mData.get(i).tipo));
    viewHolder.tipouno.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(getColorIdentifier(context, mData.get(i).tipo)));
    if(mData.get(i).tipo2 != null){viewHolder.tipodue.setText(getStringIdentifier(context, mData.get(i).tipo2));
    viewHolder.tipodue.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(getColorIdentifier(context, mData.get(i).tipo2)));}
    else viewHolder.tipodue.setText("");
    viewHolder.numero.setText(String.valueOf(mData.get(i).numero));
    viewHolder.img.setImageResource(getImageIdentifier(context, mData.get(i).immagine));

}


public void selectPosition(int position) {
    mSelectedPosition = position;
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData != null ? mData.size() : 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView nome;
    public TextView tipouno;
    public TextView tipodue;
    public TextView numero;
    public ImageView img;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nome = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        tipouno = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tipoprimo);
        tipodue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tiposecondo);
        numero = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numero);
        img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.immagine);
    }
}

public static int getStringIdentifier(Context context, String name) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", context.getPackageName());
}

public static int getImageIdentifier(Context context, String name) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}

public static int getColorIdentifier(Context context, String name) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "color", context.getPackageName());
}
```

}

Class PokemonBase:

```
public class PokemonBase {
int numero;
String nome;
String tipo;
String tipo2;
String immagine;

PokemonBase(){

}
```

}

element.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="72dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/immagine"
    android:maxHeight="40dp"
    android:maxWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:transitionName="profile"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/nome"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:transitionName="name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/tipoprimo" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" "
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/tiposecondo" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/numero"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "**if you need the code just ask what you need**", it is you who should post those codes which are suspected, we have no idea what is the structure of your code

Comment: what is **pollo**, why there is a special handling when `i==0`?

Comment: pardon, my fault, **pollo** is useless now ahahah forgot to delete it

Comment: actually this part of code looks fine. You should check whether this `List<PokemonBase> data` is being modified after you create the adapter, outside of the adapter.

Comment: `List<PokemonBase> data` never gets modified: i get it from a database when the application starts and never touch it

Comment: umm, maybe add your element.xml to your post as well

Comment: Can you please post your `R.layout.element` XML layout code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your layout to something like this

```
<LinearLayout>

    <ImageView/>
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right">
       ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Only the `layout_weight` and `layout_width` I have changed, I skipped those part which no changes needed.

Comment: it seems to work, i test it a while and then i'll mark you as answer, thank you :D

but why this little changes make it work?

Comment: it is because the layout is measured when it is first displayed. In your original layout, your pokemon number get as much space as possible. So if the view is first used by **Ivysaur**, the length of the linear layout, parent of the name,  is small. When it is reused by **Charmander**,  it do not have enough space to fill the space, thus chop it off. There is also a **dirty** method to fix it by setting layout_width of `nome` as `wrap_content`, but this create another problem, i.e. if the name is actually super long, though it may never happen, your pokemon number will be pushed off screen.